# minimum no of swaps required to make sure no two cats or dogs are at adjacent place

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

we are given an array and elements of the array represents cats and dogs. We have to rearrange the elements by swapping such that no two cats or dogs are at adjacent place.

Note: We can swap an element of the array with any element.

```
Eg: given input: [d,c,d,c,c]
exp o/p: 2
Explanation : 
step 1: swap index-0 and index-1 =>[c,d,d,c,c]
step 2: swap index2 and index-3  =>[c,d,c,d,c]

input: [c,d,d,c,c,c]
exp o/p : not possible
```

Comment: If you can swap an element with any other one, the problem is very simple O(n) and you could find it very easily. It would be sligthly more difficult with you can only swap with an adjacant element, as you did in your first example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Check whether either of them is `n == m + 1` or whether `n == m` is true.
2. If this is NOT the case it is impossible and `return`.
3. If `n == m + 1` we know that on all even indices there must be an `n` and for all odd ones there must be a `m`.
4. **EDIT:** If `n == m` the starting value does matter! If the number of swaps is the most essential part of the algorithm run step 5 on both possible variations and compare the length of the resulting sub arrays. **[1]** Thank you @Ishpreet for pointing this out!
5. Iterate through the array, check for whether there is an `n` or `m`. If the value is wrong for the respective index (e.g. on index 0 there is a `m` instead of a `n`, note that index down in either the array for wrongly placed `n's` or `m's`.
6. After that, swap the written down index values in the array based on the two sub arrays.

> [C, C, C, C, D, D, D, D]
>
> Wrong C = [1, 3]
>
> Wrong D = [4, 6]
>
> Swap(1,4) and (3,6)
>
> Result: [C, D, C, D, C, D, C, D]

**[1]** *The complexity of the algorithm doesn't change due to this.*

Comment: You still have to compare both placements(even and odd). Like incase of `CDCDCDCDDC` array. The expected array can be `DCDCDCDCDC` or `CDCDCDCDCD`. So you have to compare both of them to find which one requires minimum number of swaps.

Comment: @assoron, is it possible to predict the min swaps without actually swapping?

Comment: Depends on what you mean with predicting? You need certain information about the number and positions of the elements to make that prediction, so I don't see how you would cut out any of the above steps before step 6 which is the swap itself.